# What font is used on the Programmers Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, design, fonts

I would like to know the name of the body font used in the Programmers Stack Exchange site. I was keen on using it in my blog.

PS: Sorry, I do not know if this is the place to ask this, but I felt that the question didn't fit in any of the programming sites.

edit: Font here I mean the font of the question body, not of the header/title section.

Comment: Perhaps http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Are you talking about the body text or the logo text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The handwritten font in the title, top nav and section header is [House Whiteboard](http://callsignkatejones.deviantart.com/art/House-Whiteboard-font-64929545). Yes, it is actually Hugh Laurie's handwriting. ("It's Not Lupus!")

From [Site Design, round 2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2)

You can read about the progression of the design via the three main posts surrounding it:

[Design Ideas for Programmers Site [Closed]](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/design-ideas-for-programmers-site-closed)

[Site Design, round 2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2)

[New Design Launched](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/687/new-design-launched)

You should be able to find out what you need to know via those posts, or by analyzing the CSS and HTML.  If not, you can probably leave a comment on one of those posts asking for more specific information.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy paste the text into Microsoft Word

Here you go.

[image: font yeah?]

Comment: -1 - that's clearly not what the OP asked. He's looking for the font used in the logo.

Comment: That is what I thought too, but I reckon OP must have forgotten to mention it. " programmers stack exchange site" is kinda vague IMO.

Comment: Haha there's absolutely nothing "clear" about the question.